# Decode multiple variables coded by MD5

Tags: php, md5

I have the coding of this variables:

```
  $secret = 'jsdkhf8fh3fewk';
  $path = '/foo.pdf';
  $expire = time() + 3600; // one hour valid
  $md5 = base64_encode(md5($secret . $path . $expire, true)); 
  $md5 = strtr($md5, '+/', '-_'); 
  $md5 = str_replace('=', '', $md5);
```

Is there a way to rollback to the original variables `$secret,$path and $expire`?

The problem is that this `$md5` is part of url and it is used to validate the request. How server can validate request with it?

Comment: Hashing it is hashing, isn't encryption. Hashing is one-way.

Comment: no roll back for md5 hashing, instead utilizing salt hashing for roll back.

Comment: So in this case I cannot rollback?

Comment: you cannot rollback md5. http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php check the link salt encryption.

Comment: why would you want to? what is the scenario?

Comment: you are saying "they" are you trying to crack someone else's code?

Comment: I have just to understand how to validate request 'cause I am making a server API

Comment: @user1938193 `base64_encode` **with** `md5` does **not** make the hash **more** secure.

Comment: How a server can use this value to validate a request?

Answer (score 0):

Hashing is not encryption. `MD5` is a hashing algorithm. Hashing is one-way, so **you cannot** decrypt an hash. What you can do is try to guess the original `$secret . $path . $expire` string by try to match a large number of possible combination. But even then md5 isn't a collision-resistant hash function, so there are no guarantee even then.